# Helm: no chart version found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I keep getting similar error even though the chart exists. Is it not SemV2 versioning?

**Error:**

```
The helm deployment failed because: Error: chart "ap983546-test-api" matching 2.0.0-featureesp2606-8 not found in artifactory index. (try 'helm repo update'): no chart version found for ap983546-test-api-2.0.0-featureesp2606-8
```

**Command Ran:**

```
helm upgrade ap983546-test-api artifactory/ap983546-test-api --set liveSlot=blue,blue.enabled=false,blueImage.tag=2.0.0-featureesp2606-6,greenImage.tag=2.0.0-featureesp2606-8 --wait -f charts/ap983546-test-api/values_rks.yaml --version 2.0.0-featureesp2606-8 --install
```

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the version of the helm chart is not there. To check the chart versions in your helm chart you can try running the command `helm search repo <repo_name>/<chart_name>` -l. This command will list all the versions of the chart you wanted to install and can help you to install the desired version